# localization with TDOA under Doppler shift

Tags: signal-detection, filtering, peak-detection, localization

In a localization system, I use the TDOA (Time Difference of arrival) method. The transmitter is moving at a speed v and its communication signal is received on 3 receivers at different times. For a receiver, the time of arrival is detected by suitable filtering. But here I have a problem. Does the doppler shift have an impact on localization.

In other words, should the doppler shift be compensated before the arrival peak is detected or can the peak be detected without taking the doppler shift into account?

Answer (score 0):

What your detection filter does is form the inner product of the received signal and a known signal vector.

Now, if your Doppler shift causes the product to disappear, then you get a zero result, and can't detect your signal at all. This happens, for example, if you just multiply your signal with an alternating sequence of -1, +1, -1, +1, …; in terms of harmonic oscillations, it happens whenever the sequence you multiply your transmit signal with has a period that fits an integer time into observation window. Doppler shifts cause a modulation – i.e., a multiplication with a sequence representing a harmonic oscillation!

To summarize: Doppler shifts will reduce the SNR of your observation, and hence negatively affect your time difference estimate's variance. In the extreme case, it can completely erase cross-correlation, and then you lose one TOA pair; with only three receivers, that's when your system falls apart and can't do *any* estimate anymore.

Couple of things you can do:

1. form Doppler hypotheses and try pre-correcting a set of possible Doppler shifts that seem plausible, especially given previous trajectories of the transmitter
2. be broadband; by choosing two or more bands at a sufficiently large separation, you can enforce that you never get two complete cancellations
3. more receivers
4. something else than TDO